# Read in JSON at runtime in React Webpack app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, runtime

I have a small React/Webpack app where I import a JSON file at the top of the file. At buildtime, the contents of the JSON are read into the resulting bundle.js. If I then make changes the the JSON file I need to re-build the app for the React app to change.

Is there a way to get it so the React app will read in the JSON file at runtime?

One idea I had was to manually edit the output HTML to read mydata.js (in addition to bundle.js) and then mydata.js would just assign window.mydata to the data. Then the React app would read in from the window global object. But I think that's a hacky solution curious to see if there are better paths. Thanks!

Comment: How slow is the rebuild? If you have mydata.js and assign it to window.mydata - you need to refresh the browser. If the app is small those two approaches would have similar waiting time

Comment: There is a JSON server package that can create fake API requests and have JSON files manipulated, https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the json file in the public folder of your react app (so it's served as a static asset) and then use a fetch call to access it. Attention: this will be much slower at execution time (as the browser needs to execute an additional HTTP request).